# Digital Ocean nginx/sites-enabled question

Tags: python, nginx, digital-ocean

I've written the wrong name when writing this in the terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio-project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

so when I hit this command:

```
sudo nginx -t
```

its comes up with:

```
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/portfolio-project" failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
```

nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

question is - how do I delete amend this portfolio-project as thats the wrong folder level. I have already written this command to say porfolio which is the correct name but now I don't know how to delete the 'portfolio-project' thingy.

Many thanks! 
RG

Comment: Hi! You don't have to add this to the question, but what do you see when you issue the `ls -l` command in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: It says: default   portfolio.  Portfolio-project.  (so I want to remove portfolio-project but how would I do that? ) thanks!

Comment: As @icedwater suggested. use `ls -l` or `ls -la` (to see hidden files). Also you might want to run `vi sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio-project` to open this file in the vi editor, or you can open this up in your editor of choice. Make sure that you have the correct nginx configuration in that file. 9 times out of 10 the issue will be because these files are configured incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

Try:
You have to edit the `etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio-project` fle. Either use vi or nano ( i use vi below):

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio-project
```

then change the line:

```
include proxy_params;
```

to:

```
include /path/to/proxy_params
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've made a typo while creating the initial **soft** link (`ln -s`), you can safely delete the link without affecting the original file:

```
sudo ln -s /path/oops /destination  # oops
rm /destination/oops
sudo ln -s /path/correct /destination
```

Please do not try this with critical files and *hard* links (no `-s`).

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the wrong softlink as if it were a file using the 'rm' command as such. For example, if you did this

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio-project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

then you would have to execute the following command

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/portfolio-project
```

and then simply re-link the correct file as such

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/correct-one /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Hope this helps!